# Blazor Checkbox two-way binding and change event

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

What is the correct way to bind a checkbox and have an event fire when that checkbox changes?  I have tried a couple of different ways all not working exactly as I had hoped.  Note the checkbox is in a component.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@IsChecked" @onchange="CheckboxChanged">
@code{
      [Parameter]
      public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = true;
      private void CheckboxChanged()
      {
           Console.WriteLine($"Checkbox changed {IsChecked}");
      }
}
```

When the page loads it reads the value that is given to `IsChecked`, and when the CheckBox is checked the method fires.  However, the value for `IsChecked` is not updated.  Then if the binding value for `IsChecked` is changed outside of the component, the method does not fire but the value for `IsChecked` is changed (should note that UI is updated correctly).

I figured I needed an actual bind like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="IsChecked" @onchange="CheckboxChanged" >
```

However, this gives an error that `onchange` is used two or more

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="IsChecked" @onclick="CheckboxChanged" >
```

When the user clicks the checkbox it does fire the method however, `IsChecked` is at the old value (I am assuming the click happens before the bind).  Then if the value for `IsChecked` is changed outside of the component, once again the method does not fire.

What is the correct way?

Comment: You are exposing the `IsChecked` as a parameter, meaning the caller/parent controls the actual state of the checkbox, not the checkbox component. You should expose the `OnChange` as an [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#eventcallback) and handle the actuall change on the parent. Also on the parent, perform the state change: `IsChecked = !IsChecked`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two issues with your code/component:

1. You should not modify `[Parameters]` within your code.  These are set whenever the component updates.
2. The bind uses the `OnChanged` event to update `isChecked`, so you can't also use it.

Here's commented code that works.

1. Uses an internal field to hold the checkbox state.
2. Wired up the `OnInput` event.

```
@page "/"
<input type="checkbox" checked="@isChecked" @oninput="CheckboxChanged">

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = true;

    // Internal field holding checkbox state
    private bool isChecked;

    // updates the internal value whwenever the component is updated
    // You may not want that??
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        isChecked = this.IsChecked;
    }

    private void CheckboxChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the checkbox state
        var value = e.Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"Checkbox changed {IsChecked}");
      }
}
```

Comment: [Polite]... Why don't you use the `@onchange` directive ? Why use the `@oninput` directive, that though in the current context works exactly like `@onchange`, still feels a lesser choice... It is not clear from the question whether the user creates a two-way binding between a parent component and the component hosting the input checkbox element. Your code, however, defines only a parameter property named `IsChecked`, which implies a one way component binding, right ? If so, `isChecked = this.IsChecked;` should be placed in the OnInitialized{Async} pair, not in `OnParametersSet.`

Comment: If not, then you must add code to check if isChecked != this.IsChecked, and of course, you must add a call back parameter property with which you return to the parent component, the selected value

Comment: All valid comments, and hopefully instructive for anyone reading the question.   The context is always the unknown in almost any question, and without it any answer is based on a lot of guesswork!  Note the `You may not want that??` comment in the code.

Comment: `Note the You may not want that?? comment in the code.`  I've noticed it... Upvoting your answer...

Answer (score 15):

As of .NET 7 you can use the `@bind-value:after` to tap into the change event after it's happened.

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind-value="@IsChecked" @bind-value:after="CheckboxChanged">

@code{
      [Parameter]
      public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = true;
      private void CheckboxChanged()
      {
           Console.WriteLine($"Checkbox changed {IsChecked}");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Like @hans-kesting mentioned, you can use `InputCheckbox`. If you would like to have a custom logic on value changed event you can achieve it with this:

```html
<InputCheckbox ValueChanged="@((e) => CheckboxChanged(e))" ValueExpression="@(() => IsChecked)"/>
```

Note, that you cannot use `@bind-Value` and `ValueChanged` together. That's why `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression` are required to achieve similar behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

There exists also an [InputCheckbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputcheckbox) control:

```xml
  <InputCheckbox @bind-Value=@boolProperty />
```

This correctly two-way binds to a property of type `bool` (non-nullable). Note the capital **V** in `@bind-Value`.

This control needs to be inside an [EditForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editform) control.

Comment: The problem with this is there's no event in which to run custom event handling code, which is an important part of the question. Is it possible to use the component as you've shown, and also have access to a change event?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@record.IsChecked" checked="@record.IsChecked" @onchange="@((args) => CheckboxChanged((bool)args.Value))"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**