# Test that an InputCheckbox invokes a method

Tags: c#, blazor, bunit

I have an `InputCheckbox` on a page defined as:

```cs
<InputCheckbox id="my-cb" ValueChanged="@CallApi" ValueExpression="@(() => MyFlag)">


@code {
    public bool MyFlag { get; set; }

    async Task CallApi()
    {
        // call api
    }
}
```

Interactively this works, clicking on the checkbox calls my api. I use `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression` for reasons best explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71224684/blazor-checkbox-two-way-binding-and-change-event).

In my unit test I have setup a Mock of my api and want to test if the mocked api is invoked. However, finding the `<InputCheckbox/>` and invoking the Change event does not trigger the call even to `CallApi()`.

```cs
var cbx = cut.Find("#my-cb");
cbx.Change(); // does not call `CallApi`
```

I suspect because no `@onclick` method is specified (for the reasons in the post).

I have also tried changing the value of `MyFlag` which doesn't work either.

```cs
cut.Instance.MyFlag = true;
```

Comment: I don't much see the point of double-checking with javascript what you are already successfully doing in Blazor.  But my guess is you're looking for the input element before the DOM has loaded.  Try adding a button so you can call your test method after rendering finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. If you are using `ValueChanged` you need to set `Value` to `MyFlag`.
2. In `CallApi` you need to accept the value provided and set `MyFlag`.
3. In the tests you must provide a `ChangeEventArgs` instance when calling `Change`.  That should have generated an error.
4. `<InputCheckbox ...>` is ill formed and should have generated a warning.

This is my version of your page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@*Original*@
<InputCheckbox id="my-cb" Value=this.MyFlag ValueChanged=CallApi ValueExpression="() => MyFlag" />

@*Can do this is Net7.0*@
<InputCheckbox id="my-cb1" @bind-Value:get=this.MyFlag @bind-Value:set=CallApi />

@*Display the Value*@
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1 ">
    <pre>MyFlag : @this.MyFlag</pre>
</div>

@code {
    public bool MyFlag { get; set; }

    async Task CallApi(bool value)
    {
        this.MyFlag = value;
        await Task.Delay(10);
        // call api
    }
}
```

Here are three tests.  Note that `Change` needs to provide a `ChangeEventArgs` instance.

```cs
public class UnitTest1 : TestContext
{
    [Fact]
    public void CheckIndexCheckboxTrue()
    {
        // Act
        var cut = RenderComponent<SO76081912.Pages.Index>();

        var cbx = cut.Find("#my-cb");
        cbx.Change(new ChangeEventArgs() { Value=true });
        
        // Assert
        cut.Instance.MyFlag = true;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CheckIndexCheckboxFalse()
    {
        // Act
        var cut = RenderComponent<SO76081912.Pages.Index>();

        var cbx = cut.Find("#my-cb");
        cbx.Change(new ChangeEventArgs() { Value = false });

        // Assert
        cut.Instance.MyFlag = false;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CheckIndexCheckbox1True()
    {
        // Act
        var cut = RenderComponent<SO76081912.Pages.Index>();

        var cbx = cut.Find("#my-cb1");
        cbx.Change(new ChangeEventArgs() { Value = true });

        // Assert
        cut.Instance.MyFlag = true;
    }
}
```

[image]